# Is there any way to know if a hero is ranged or melee?

Tags: dota-2

I have just started playing DOTA 2, and as with any other game, I feel I am best with ranged heroes.

However, I don't know which heroes are ranged or melee. Is there any way to find out?

Comment: A simple rule that helps when learning is that STR heroes are almost always melee (exceptions: Wisp and Huskar) and INT heroes are almost always ranged (exception: Ogre Magi).

Comment: For INT heroes, exception of Dark Seer also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the "Learn" tab on the menu you can view all of the current heroes.  Each hero has tags assigned to it, such as carry, disabler, initiator, jungler, etc.  Among those tags are also "melee" and "ranged".  You can choose to set an attack type filter on that menu, or during hero selection in a game, to show only ranged heroes.

Answer (score 0):

Other than trying them out ingame, I don't know how to view this at a glance. However, the DOTA 2 wiki has a list:

> http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Category:Ranged_heroes

Beware, it contains some hero that are not in the game yet.